# How to document.getElementById() a countdown timer from javascript script into html paragraph nested within a php for loop more than once?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to output a countdown timer at the bottom of each of my auction panels within a paragraph tag where each of the paragraph tags have a unique ID. The problem is that it only works for the first auction panel in the for loop. For example the size of the array is 3 so three panels get outputted in the for loop, only the first one will have a countdown timer, the other two will not. I'm a complete newbie to javascript so i'm not sure why this is.

```html
<div class="container">    
 
    <div class="row">
          <?php   
    for($i = 1; $i <= sizeof($auctionidarray); $i++)
               {
       ?>
      
         <a href="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>?pageID=AuctionPage0<?php echo $auctionidarray[$i-1]?>"><div class="col-sm-4"> 
      
             <div class="panel panel-success">
      
                 <div class="panel-heading">  <?php echo $titlearray[$i-1]?>  </div> 
        <div class="panel-body">
            
           <img src="Uploads/<?php echo $auctionidarray[$i-1].$zero.".".$imgextarray[$i-1]?>" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%; height:400px;" alt="Image"></div>
        <div class="panel-footer">Buy 50 mobiles and get a gift card
            
            <p id="demo_<?php$auctionidarray[$i-1]?>"></p>
        
        </div>
                 </div>
             </div></a>
             

         <script>
// Set the date we're counting down to

var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 5, 2019 15:37:25").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
 
var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    
    // Find the distance between now and the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;
    
    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo_<?php$auctionidarray[$i-1]?>").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
    + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
    
    // If the count down is over, write some text 
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
        document.getElementById("demo_<?php$auctionidarray[$i-1]?>").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
    }
    
    
    
    // If the count down is over, write some text 
   
}, 1000);

</script>    
   
       <?php
      
       }
   ?> 
    </div>
```

[image: Example of what it looks like in web browser]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have access to your array, but try replacing:

```
<p id="demo_<?php$auctionidarray[$i-1]?>"></p>
```

With:

```
<p id="demo_<?php echo $i; ?>"></p>
```

Then replace the two instances of:

```
document.getElementById("demo_<?php$auctionidarray[$i-1]?>")...
```

With:

```
document.getElementById("demo_<?php echo $i; ?>")...
```

That being said, running the same script three times (or however many times your loop iterates) isn't very good practice. An alternative could be move the **script** tag outside of your for loop, then do something along the lines of:

```
<script>
var NUM_COUNTERS_TO_DISPLAY = 3;

function displayCounters() {
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the distance between now and the count down date
    var distance = countDownDate - now;

    ...

    for(var i = 0; i < NUM_COUNTERS_TO_DISPLAY; i++) {
        // If the counter has run out and the counters have been updated
        if(distance <= 0 && x != null) {
            document.getElementById("demo_" + i).innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
        }

        else if(distance > 0) {
            document.getElementById("demo_" + i).innerHTML =
            days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
        }
    }
}

displayCounters(NUM_COUNTERS_TO_DISPLAY); // Show the counters when the page loads

// Update the countdown every second
var x = setInterval(function() {
    displayCounters();
}, 1000);
</script>
```